# SQL statement to accumulate total given uniquely identifiable values

Tags: sql, apache-flink, analytics

This is Flink SQL app, but those details aren't too important for my issue. I need a SQL query which accumulates a total amount for each person's phone number, email address, or bank account and there name fuzzy matches over a 15 day window.

Some example sql:

```
CREATE TABLE events (
  name STRING,
  phone STRING,
  email STRING,
  bank_account STRING,
  amount DOUBLE,
  timestamp TIMESTAMP(3),
  WATERMARK FOR timestamp AS timestamp - INTERVAL '5' SECOND
) WITH (
  'connector' = 'kafka',
  'topic' = 'my-topic',
  'properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'localhost:9092',
  'properties.group.id' = 'test-group',
  'scan.startup.mode' = 'earliest-offset',
  'format' = 'json'
);

CREATE TABLE person_totals (
  key STRING,
  total DOUBLE,
  window_start TIMESTAMP(3),
  window_end TIMESTAMP(3)
) WITH (
  'connector' = 'print'
);

INSERT INTO person_totals
SELECT CONCAT_WS('|', phone, email, bank_account),
  SUM(amount),
  TUMBLE_START(timestamp, INTERVAL '15' DAY),
  TUMBLE_END(timestamp, INTERVAL '15' DAY)
FROM (
  SELECT name, phone, email, bank_account, amount, timestamp
  FROM events
  WHERE phone IS NOT NULL OR email IS NOT NULL OR bank_account IS NOT NULL
) e1
JOIN (
  SELECT name, phone, email, bank_account
  FROM events
  WHERE phone IS NOT NULL OR email IS NOT NULL OR bank_account IS NOT NULL
) e2
ON (fuzzy_match(e1.name, e2.name) >= 0.9 OR e1.phone = e2.phone OR e1.email = e2.email OR e1.bank_account = e2.bank_account)
GROUP BY TUMBLE(timestamp, INTERVAL '15' DAY), CONCAT_WS('|', phone, email, bank_account);
```

This gets me about 98% of what I need, but is incorrect for one specific example set. The problem the GROUP BY CONCAT_WS('|', phone, email, bank_account) doesn't work correclty for null values.

Take this example input:

```
INSERT INTO events
VALUES 
    (1, '2023-04-01 10:00:00.000', 'John Doe', '1234567890', NULL, 2000.00),
    (2, '2023-04-03 12:00:00.000', 'John Dor', '1234567890', 'johndoe@example.com', 3000.00),
    (3, '2023-04-05 17:00:00.000', 'Jane Smith', NULL, 'janesmith@example.com', 1500.00),
    (4, '2023-04-06 19:00:00.000', 'John Doe', NULL, 'johndoe@example.com', 5001.00)
    (5, '2023-04-07 10:00:00.000', 'John Doe', '1234567890', NULL, 2000.00);
```

My expected output for alerts over $10,000 should look like this:

```
`id | amount | accumulation_amount | matched_ids
 4    5001.00  10001.00              1, 2
 5    2000.00. 12001.00              1, 2, 4`
```

Essentially id 2 is like a "bridge" event which links id 1 with 4 because it uses the same phone number in id 1 and same eamil in id 4. The same logic applies for id 5.

How would I write the SQL to accomodate for this case? Again the app is for Apache Flink, but thinking in general SQL will probably get us close enough.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Consider normalizing your model, and using IDs instead of 'fuzzy matching' of names.